# Kodein scoped singleton do not persists when injected from multiple classes

Tags: android, kotlin, scope, singleton

I am trying to inject the singleton dependencies of config manager in different modules for which I c created a Scope and Context containing StandardScopeRegistry. But it doesn't work. Following is the sample code:

**Approach 1**

class A.kt

```
import org.kodein.di.bindings.Scope
import org.kodein.di.bindings.ScopeRegistry
import org.kodein.di.bindings.StandardScopeRegistry

object SingletonScope : Scope<GlobalKodeinContext> {

    override fun getRegistry(context: GlobalKodeinContext): ScopeRegistry =
            context.standardScopeRegistry as? ScopeRegistry
                    ?: StandardScopeRegistry().also { context.standardScopeRegistry = it }

}

class GlobalKodeinContext {

    var standardScopeRegistry = StandardScopeRegistry()

}
```

Bindings.kt

```
val deploymentConfigManagerBinding = Kodein.Module("deployment_config_manager", false) {
      bind<IConfigManager>() with scoped(SingletonScope).singleton { ConfigManager() }
}
```

class B.kt

```
private val configManager: IConfigManager by kodein.on(context = GlobalKodeinContext()).instance<IConfigManager>()

configManager.initializeConfigs(values)
```

class C.kt

```
private val configManager: IConfigManager by kodein.on(context = GlobalKodeinContext()).instance<IConfigManager>()

configManager.getConfigs()
```

**Approach 2** *I do not prefer static context objects, but tried anyway as nothing works*

GlobalKodeinContext.kt

```
class GlobalKodeinContext {
    companion object {
        var appContext: Application? = null //Setting this in MainApplication with `this`
    }
}
```

Bindings.kt

```
val deploymentConfigManagerBinding = Kodein.Module("deployment_config_manager", false) {
    bind<IConfigManager>() with scoped(WeakContextScope.of<Application>()).singleton { ConfigManager() }

    registerContextTranslator { context: Application -> context.applicationContext }
}
```

A.kt

```
override val kodeinContext = kcontext(GlobalKodeinContext.appContext)

private val configManager: IConfigManager by instance()

configManager.initializeConfigs(values)
```

B.kt

```
override val kodeinContext = kcontext(GlobalKodeinContext.appContext)

private val configManager: IConfigManager by instance()

configManager.getConfigs()
```

configManager.getConfigs() gives null pointer exception in both approaches as the configurations are not initialized for the singleton object injected in class C.

I believe the context creation is incorrect. Please help. Thank you!